# Invoking a website through Eclipse (Mars 2), selenium(2,52,0) on java using firefox(ver 47) throws an error "firefox has stopped working"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Environment: Eclipse(Mars 2), Selenium(2.52.0), Firefox (version 47).

A basic script even after incorporating suggestions to use "marionette", updated the path in system, upon execution throws an error "Firefox has stopped working ".

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

        public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              DesiredCapabilities capabilities =       DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
              capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
              WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
              driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
              String title = driver.getTitle();
              System.out.println(title);

         }
```

Appreciate, if anyone could help me out.

br,

Comment: Downgrade to FireFox 45/46, or use new Marionete driver (but it also has own issues), see this for details: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2110

Comment: I am ok to revert back to the previous version but, I am not able to find out the installer for Firefox 45 /46 on the the net.                                      Could you please help me with the installer.

Comment: See this link https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/ there are all old versions of Firefox there. You must disable automatic upgrades after installing the older version.

Comment: thanks Kordirko.... I managed to download Firefox ver 46 from the provided link and the scripts run properly on Firefox.

Comment: If this question has already been answered or is no longer needed, please delete it.